# Importing an excel sheet with many empty cells into R

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, r

I have a big excel sheet that have lots of empty cells. I'd like to import it in R. I'm fine if in R, all the empty cells are replaced by "NoData".

Replacing all empty cells by "NoData" on Excel and then creating a CSV would take way too much time. What is the easiest way to import this Excel sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually replacing empty cells with "NoData" is a trivial task.

Just select all the cells, then from the Home ribbon choose Find & Select, then Replace.

Leave the "Find what" box empty.  For "Replace with", enter NoData. Click Options then check the option for "Match entire cell contents".  Click Replace All.

Then Save As CSV - you're done!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, that's what I ended up doing. But it took some time to do it and it is not the first time that I am facing this kind of issue. I hoped a faster solution would exist than having to select all the empty cells. (Those empty cells do not form a column or anything easy to select and the data table is very big).

Comment: You can select all the cells in the entire table.  The Replace operation will only affect the empty cells.

Comment: Oh I didn't got this point! Ok, thank you!